# Code review of this portion of Linq Filters

Tags: c#, linq, optimization

I am a newbie of c #, I would like to know if I can remove the for each and do a single operation with Linq. I would like to return an IEnumerable with already filtered. is it possible to do this? Every suggestion is welcome, thank you very much

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Linq
{
class Oggetto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
    public int Deleted { get; set; }
}
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IEnumerable<Oggetto> lista = new List<Oggetto> {
            new Oggetto(){ Id = 1, MyProperty = "Propr1", Deleted = 0 },
            new Oggetto(){ Id = 1, MyProperty = "Propr2", Deleted = 1 },
            new Oggetto(){ Id = 2, MyProperty = "Prop3", Deleted = 0 },
            new Oggetto(){ Id = 3, MyProperty = "Propr4", Deleted = 0 },
            new Oggetto(){ Id = 3, MyProperty = "Prop5", Deleted = 1 }
        };


        foreach (var item in lista.Where(x => x.Deleted == 1).GroupBy(x => x.Id).Select(g => g.First()))
        {
            item.MyProperty = string.Join(",", lista.Where(t => t.Id == item.Id).Select(x => x.MyProperty).ToArray());
            Console.WriteLine(item.Id);
            Console.WriteLine(item.MyProperty);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: single linq statements are not more efficient! and usually much hard to read and debug. Making it as small as possible does not make it better! this is i think more important... as code you can read is better than code you cant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [projection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/projection-operations) for this.

```
        var orderedList = lista.GroupBy(x => x.Id)
                               .Where(x => x.Any(y => y.Deleted == 1))
                               .Select(x => new Oggetto
                                            {
                                                Id = x.Key, MyProperty = string.Join(",", x.Select(v => v.MyProperty))
                                            });

        foreach (var item in orderedList)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Id);
            Console.WriteLine(item.MyProperty);
        }
```

Anyway, as @Alex said you shoud replace `Deleted` field type to `bool` and as said by @Marco Salerno start programming in English you'll not regret.

Comment: This is nearly unreadable code. You also made a major error. You changed the original lists items (elements `[1]` and `[4]` are changed after your query) which is completely unacceptable. Sorry.

Comment: Yep bad idea to answer from my phone. I voted to delete my answer. And up voted yours.

Answer (score 1):

First of all **STOP** programming in Italian, start doing it in English.

Anyway, this should be a better approach:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        List<Item> items = new List<Item> {
            new Item{ Id = 1, MyProperty = "Propr1", Deleted = 0 },
            new Item{ Id = 1, MyProperty = "Propr2", Deleted = 1 },
            new Item{ Id = 2, MyProperty = "Prop3", Deleted = 0 },
            new Item{ Id = 3, MyProperty = "Propr4", Deleted = 0 },
            new Item{ Id = 3, MyProperty = "Prop5", Deleted = 1}
        };

        foreach (IGrouping<int,Item> group in items.GroupBy(x => x.Id).ToList())
        {
            List<Item> groupItems = group.ToList();
            Item deletedItem = groupItems.Where(x => x.Deleted == 1).FirstOrDefault();
            if(deletedItem != null)
            {
                deletedItem.MyProperty = string.Join(",", groupItems.Select(x => x.MyProperty).ToArray());
                Console.WriteLine(deletedItem.Id);
                Console.WriteLine(deletedItem.MyProperty);
            }
        }
    }
}

class Item
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
    public int Deleted { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Make everything to `List` at the earliest stage trashes memory and is not needed in the early filter stages because you just don't know yet if you need the list or not (keep the `IEnumerable` instead). Also, you do not create anything that could be used later (e.g. a real collection of something).

Answer (score 1):

First of all I would avoid the `groupBy` statement. This is a lot of unneded overhead. You can use `distinct` instead. This will give you all the IDs you need to know.

```
var ids = lista.Where(x => x.Deleted).Select(x => x.Id).Distinct();
```

You can then select all the elements that you need with:

```
var items = ids.Select(i => lista.Where(x => x.Id == i));
```

which results in a `List of Lists`. For the ease of use I would convert this to a `Dictionary<K, V>` (int this case it's `Dictionary<long, List<string>>` as a final step:

```
var dictionary = items.ToDictionary(l => l.First().Id, l => l.Select(o => o.MyProperty).ToList());
```

You now got a "nice and filtered" collection you can use any way you like (or just output it)

```
foreach (var item in dictionary)
{
     Console.WriteLine($"Id: {item.Key}");
     Console.WriteLine($"Properties: {string.Join(", ", item.Value)}");
}
```

I also changed your class a little bit to:

```
class Oggetto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
    // bool instead of int - Deleted has only 2 states
    public bool Deleted { get; set; }
}
```